# How to keep some variables fixed during the search of nsga2R?

Tags: r, optimization, genetic-algorithm

I'm using NSGA2R to get the fitness value of the best solution that has 10 variables. However, I would like to keep 4 of them fix through all generations and 6 generate randomly by the algorithm, How do we do that with the nsga2R optimization algorithm?

Sample of the code that I'm using now:

```r
NSGA <- nsga2R(fn = function(x)  myfitnessFun(x,m,10), varNo = 10, objDim = 2, generations = 1,
               mprob = 0.2, popSize = 50, cprob = 0.8,
               lowerBounds = c(rep(1, 1)), upperBounds = c(rep(N, 10)))
```

I'm looking to find the best 10 sensors locations out of N sensors that satisfied our fitness function. The question is how to fix, as an example, 4 of these 10? where the remaining 6 will be randomly selected.

As our data has the coordinates of these sensors: sample of this data

```
(structure(c(47.4, 47.6105263157895, 47.8210526315789, 48.0315789473684, 
5.71, 5.71, 5.71, 5.71, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(4L, 3L)))
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please make your question reproducible by pasting a sample of your data: use `dput(head(your_data_sample, n))` where `n` is enough data to demonstrate the problem. This makes it easier for others to test and verify solutions.

Comment: Thank you @peter. I tried to make it more clear!

Comment: I am not familiar with the ` nsga2R` package. Your example is not reproducible as neither `myfitnessFun` nor `N` seem to be defined. Check out [MRE] to make your question is reproducible.